# How to avoid duplicate HTTP calls with rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a module where the client listens to websocket events from the server, and every time an update event is received, a HTTP call is made to update the data set on the UI.
I am running into a problem, where for a certain type of operation, the server send about 40 update events within a span of 10 seconds and the UI triggers 40 API calls in the span of 10s. The server does not seem able to process all these requests.

I was wondering if there is an rxjs way to handle this problem where, when an API call to the server is still pending for the same request, I have to wait for it to complete before I make the same request again.

```
listen(wstopic) {   
  return this.wsService.subscribeEndPoint(wstopic).pipe(
    switchMap((event) => {
      if (event === 'UPDATE') {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/monitoring/eventlog`, { params })
      } else {
        return of(null)
      }
    })
  )
}

listen('some/topic').subscribe((data) => {
  if(data) {
    // Append data to array
  }
});
```

I want this part to be called, only if this same call is not already in progress

```
if (event === 'UPDATE') {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/monitoring/eventlog`, { params })
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with rxjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look on `exhaustMap` instead of that `switchMap`. `switchMap` always change to the newest emission from the source, `exhaustMap` on the other side will stick with one emission until it's finished and then will go ahead with another one.

Comment: The one catch in my case in using exhaustMap is that, when n-th request is pending, and n+1 is the final request (which arrives before n is complete), then n-th request becomes the last executed request, while n+1 might still need to be executed as it is the one with the most current data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinctUntilChanged` with a custom comparer function to emit when the current value is different than the last one:

For example:

```js
const yourBackendData$ = from([
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
]);

yourBackendData$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.id === curr.id))
  .subscribe(console.log);

// output:
// {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)